# How to uncheck sibling checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

This is my angular table,here am showing row data when I click checkbox in a row.
my query is how can I uncheck sibling checkboxes when a checkbox is clicked?I tried to achieve this but I couldn't.

```js
var app= angular.module('myApp',[])
app.controller('myController',function($scope){

 $scope.init = function(){
  $scope.List=[
   {
    'encounterDate':'jan 11',
    'visitId':'102359',        
    'emailId':'santhosh@gmail.com'
   },
   {
    'encounterDate':'dec 2',
    'visitId':'102360',        
    'emailId':'vijay@gmail.com'
   }
  ];
  
 }

 $scope.showData = function(data){
  alert("Encounter Date :" + data.encounterDate  +" \n Visit ID:" + data.visitId +
   "\n Patient name:"+ data.patientName +"\n Age:"+ data.age +"\n Referred by:"+ data.referredBy +"\n Email: "+ data.emailId)

 }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>     
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController" ng-init="init()">
<div class="container">
 
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>S.no</th>
    <th>Action</th>
    <th>Encounter Date</th>
    <th>Visit ID</th>        
    <th>Email ID</th>    
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat='data in List'>
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox'  class="checkBox"></td>
    <td>{{data.encounterDate}}</td>
    <td>{{data.visitId}}</td>        
    <td>{{data.emailId}}</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody> 
 </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried this its not working..

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {

              // uncheck sibling checkboxes (checkboxes on the same row)
              $(this).siblings().prop('checked', false);

              // uncheck checkboxes in the same column
              $('div').find('input[type="checkbox"]:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').not(this).prop('checked', false);

            });
```

Any suggesstion? Can Any one let me know that,What I did wrong?

Comment: I think you need `radio` button, And don't mix DOM manipulation with AngularJS

Comment: input[type=checkbox] looks like has no siblings on your code...

Answer (score 1):

First add ng-model to your checkboxes

```
<td><input type='checkbox' ng-model="data.checked" ng-change="checkSibling(data)"  class="checkBox"></td>
```

and use ng-change to uncheck siblings when a checkbox is checked

```
$scope.checkSibling = function(rowData){
    angular.forEach($scope.List, function(value, key) {
        if(value.visitId != rowData.visitId)
            value.checked = false;
    });
}
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/aULuPTawc2k7SOFFb5HI?p=preview)